# Phoenix Elixir - Refactoring function to be functional

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm pretty new to Elixir and Phoenix, but I'm finding it really really cool. I come from a background in Rails.

Given this changeset for instance:

```
def signup(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username])
    |> validate_required([:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username])
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 3)
    |> validate_length(:username, max: 20)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i)
    |> password_match()
    |> gen_hash_password()
    |> set_defaults
  end
```

I have front-end code that doesn't allow a user to post the signup form without a password & password_confirmation, but when executing tests I want to have a test that checks for empty values being passed. The way I got around it was by writing in a very procedural way an if else branch:

```
defp gen_hash_password(signup) do
  password = get_change(signup, :password)
  if password == nil
    signup
  else
    hash = Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password)
    signup |> put_change(:password_hash, hash)
  end
end
```

Otherwise, the test will fail as Bcrypt will be given a `nil` string and will be unable to compute the hash.
This doesn't seem very elegant though and I was wondering how I could go on writing a better version of it.

My first thought was to do an early return after the validates have been piped, by checking if the record was still valid at that point, but then I cannot really return earlier like I would in other languages.

My second thought was verifying if it was valid, something like:

```
if valid? do
  struct
  |> pipe the remaining changes
else
  struct
end
```

But I don't seem to find a way of querying the struct validity inside the changeset itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When the `changeset` is passed to your `gen_hash_password`, you can simply check for validity of the changeset with `changeset.valid?`. If it isn't valid, simply pass changeset back as their is no point in hashing a password for a record that you won't persist.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
defp encrypt_password(changeset) do
  if changeset.valid? do
    changeset
    |> put_change(:password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(changeset.changes.password))
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than what I have - though I would still need to either make a general function that would then call the the hashing and remaining functions in case the changeset was valid or return the struct, or add this to all subsequently called functions in the changeset pipeline to prevent them from also being called. It's mostly pedantic my question, but was just wondering if I was missing something utterly obvious.

Comment: IMO there is no need to make a genric function for hashing. Just call the `Comeonin` function directly. If the changeset is valid, it'll be hashed. If it isn't for any reason (including a nil password), it'll avoid calling the hash function.

I typically will short circuit subsequent changeset-related functions like the above. You could take it a step further and pass `changeset.valid?` to these functions but it's just not worth it I don't think.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I tried doing `|> put_change(:password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(params[:password]))` after the validations, and it will throw: `** (ArgumentError) The password and salt should be strings and the salt (before encoding) should be 16 bytes long` ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on your original intent, but answering the question stated in the title: instead of `if` dancing, in Erlang/Elixir one does pattern matching.

```
defp gen_hash_password(signup) do
  signup
  |> get_change(:password)
  |> do_signup()
end

defp do_signup(nil), do: signup
defp do_signup(password) do
  hash = Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(password)
  put_change(signup, :password_hash, hash)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice to know and I will certainly use it in other places.